# Problem with spinner on item selected

Tags: android

I have a problem with spinner. I am trying to create a spinner control which will do something on selection change.
However I have noticed that when I call the `Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListner()` the inner `onItemSelected()` method gets called (even though no change has yet to have been made to the spinner).
my code requires this method does not get called before it is actually changed. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok.. In that case what you can do is to put one if condition (not satisfying the particular position on which you don't want spinner method to respond to ) above the block that responses to change in spinner item.

Comment: Yea that would probably work but it would make my code very ugly I am just giving up on this the code should not behave like this my belief is that it is a bug. I am going to change the spinner to a different selection method.